# Proper way to get numpy masked array shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When dealing with numpy ndarray, I usually get the array shape with (say for a 3d array):

```py
    data = np.random.rand(10, 10, 10)
    X, Y, Z = data.shape
    # returns (10, 10, 10) as expected
```

Now if I have a masked array with same size, and I want only the number of unmasked values, I can't use `mdata.shape`, since I'll get the total number of element, including masked values. The workaround I found is, for a masked array mdata :

```py
    mdata = data.view(np.ma.MaskedArray)
    mdata.mask = mdata<1
    X, Y, Z = (np.ma.count(mdata, axis=0),
               np.ma.count(mdata, axis=1),
               np.ma.count(mdata, axis=2))

    # (np.ma.count(data, axis=0), np.ma.count(data, axis=1), np.ma.count(data, axis=2)) : 
    # also works with ndarray data
```

My question is then : is there a cleaner way to get the number of "valid" elements in each dimension of an array, masked or not ?

Cheers

Edit : changed "size" to "count" in the example + MWE

Comment: can you post your sample `mdata` ?

Comment: Try the row sum of the mask, or rather inveese of the mask, rhe number of `False` in each row.

Comment: Demonstrate.  I don't think `np.ma.size` is doing what you want.  If `mdata` is 3d, the number of un-masked values along `axis=0` should be a 2d array, one value along each of the other dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendations. I should precise I am looking for a way that works wheter using an ndarray and/or MaskedArray.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cleaner'?  `shape` produces a simple tuple of numbers`.  `count` produces an arrray that diifers in shape depending on the remaing axes. Two very different results.  Also look at the code for `count` to understand what it's doing.